# Ruby on rails date picker not adding to database. What can i change?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I have a checkout page with a form and I need to add 3 choices for delivery via a date picker. 
I have used code from the site that I am copying and I have been able to get the form to work on the page, however, the dates are not added to the database when submitting the order.

I have left some code that is commented out as these are features that will be added later.

```
 <script src="https://pi-test.sagepay.com/api/v1/js/sagepay-dropin.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h3> Please Enter Your Details</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <%= simple_form_for @order do |f| %>
        <%= f.input :name %>
        <%= f.input :email %>
        <%= f.input :address %>
        <%= f.input :city %>
        <%= f.input :postcode %>

        <h2>Payment Details</h2>
        <div id="sp-container"></div>
        <div class="form-actions">

          <div id="DeliveryRequirement"><div class="panel-body padding0 basketHeader font18">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 padding0">Delivery Requirements</div>
</div>

<div class="panel-body padding0 paddingBottom20 bold deliveryDateTime">

    <p>To continue to the Checkout you will need to agree to all 3 of the Delivery Requirements. Normally we have no issues at all, you can add any descriptions below that might help the driver. If you are unsure about any of the requirements please call 020-8819-6482 and we can take a look for you.</p>
    <div class="paddingBottom10">
        <a href="" onclick="$('#loginModal').modal('toggle');" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deliveryModal">
            <img src="/assets/dAccess.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="padding0 paddingTop10 paddingBottom10"><input data-val="true" data-val-required="The DeliveryConfirm field is required." id="DeliveryDates_DeliveryConfirm" name="DeliveryDates.DeliveryConfirm" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="DeliveryDates.DeliveryConfirm" type="hidden" value="false">I confirm that there is good access to the location with ample space for the driver to deliver the pallet safely.</div>
    <div class="padding0 paddingBottom10"><input data-val="true" data-val-required="The DeliveryDisagree field is required." id="DeliveryDates_DeliveryDisagree" name="DeliveryDates.DeliveryDisagree" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="DeliveryDates.DeliveryDisagree" type="hidden" value="false">Please call me to discuss my delivery as there may be some issues with access.<br><br>Please enter any special requirements you may have when we make the delivery.</div>
    <div class="padding0 paddingBottom10"><textarea class="deliveryTextArea" cols="20" id="DeliveryDates_DeliveryDisagreeMessage" name="DeliveryDates.DeliveryDisagreeMessage" rows="5"></textarea><grammarly-btn><div data-reactroot="" class="_e725ae-textarea_btn _e725ae-not_focused" style="visibility: hidden; z-index: 2;"><div class="_e725ae-transform_wrap"><div title="Protected by Grammarly" class="_e725ae-status">&nbsp;</div></div></div></grammarly-btn>

       <span style="color:red"><span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="DeliveryDates.DeliveryConfirm" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></span>
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="DeliveryDates.DeliveryDisagreeMessage" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="panel-body padding0 basketHeader font18 margin0">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 padding0">Please choose 3 different delivery dates (click here to see our delivery schedule), if you would like your delivery sooner, you can add the days and times for us to see if we can deliver any quicker.</div>
</div>

<div class="table-responsive checkouttable deliveryTable">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <div class="oldPress1">FIRST CHOICE</div>
                    <div class="paddingTop10">Next available date</div>
                    <div class="padding0">
                        <input class="text" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field First choice must be a date." data-val-required="First choice required" id="ddate1" name="ddate1" type="text" value=""><img class="ui-datepicker-trigger" src="../assets/calendar.png" alt="Select date" title="Select date">
                    </div>
                    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="DeliveryDates.DeliveryDateFirst" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </th>
                <script>
    $('#order_ddate1').ready(function(){
      var date_input=$('input[name="ddate1"]'); //our date input has the name "date"
      var container=$('.bootstrap-iso form').length>0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
      var options={
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        startDate: "+2d",
        container: container,
        todayHighlight: true,
        autoclose: true,
      };
      date_input.datepicker(options);
    })
</script>
                <th>

                    <div class="oldPress1">SECOND CHOICE</div>
                    <div class="paddingTop10">Next available date</div>
                    <div class="padding0">
                     <input class="datePickerInput marginTop10 hasDatepicker" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Second choice must be a date." data-val-required="Second choice required" id="ddate2" name="ddate2" type="text" value=""><img class="ui-datepicker-trigger" src="../assets/calendar.png" alt="Select date" title="Select date">
                    </div>
                    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="DeliveryDates.DeliveryDateSecond" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </th>
                <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var date_input=$('input[name="ddate2"]'); //our date input has the name "date"
      var container=$('.bootstrap-iso form').length>0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
      var options={
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        startDate: "+2d",
        container: container,
        todayHighlight: true,
        autoclose: true,
      };
      date_input.datepicker(options);
    })
</script>
                <th>

                    <div class="oldPress1">THIRD CHOICE</div>
                    <div class="paddingTop10">Next available date</div>
                    <div class="padding0">
                        <input class="datePickerInput marginTop10 hasDatepicker" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Third choice must be a date." data-val-required="Third choice required" id="ddate3" name="ddate3" type="text" value=""><img class="ui-datepicker-trigger" src="../assets/calendar.png" alt="Select date" title="Select date">
                    </div>
                    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="DeliveryDates.DeliveryDateThird" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </th>
                <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var date_input=$('input[name="ddate3"]'); //our date input has the name "date"
      var container=$('.bootstrap-iso form').length>0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
      var options={
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        startDate: "+2d",
        container: container,
        todayHighlight: true,
        autoclose: true,
      };
      date_input.datepicker(options);
    })
</script>
            </tr>
        </thead>


    </table>
</div>
<div class="bottomTreeBorder padding0">
    <h1 class="divTitleText">ACCEPTED PAYMENT TYPES</h1>
</div>

<div class="panel-body padding0 paddingTop20">
    <div class="col-md-6 padding0 paddingTop10">
        <img src="/images/paymentTypes.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 padding0 alignRight paddingTop10">
        <img src="/images/norton.png">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="paddingTop10">
    <a href="#" onclick="$(this).closest('form#checkoutaddress').submit()">
        <img src="/images/continue.png"></a>
</div>

    </div>









          <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-3">
          <%= f.button  :submit,"Pay #{ number_to_currency @basket.total_price, unit: "£"}" %>
        </div></div>
      <%end%>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  sagepayCheckout({ merchantSessionKey: "<%=session[:merchantSessionKey]%>" }).form();
</script>
<div class="container">
<div class="sagepay">
<%= image_tag'/assets/sagepay.jpg' %>
</div>
</div>
```

This is the server code that runs

```
SQL (4.6ms)  INSERT INTO `orders` (`name`, `email`, `address`, `city`, `postcode`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('liam ****', 'liam@liam.com', '7 liams close', 'Chertsey', 'kt91ha', '2017-04-11 14:41:24', '2017-04-11 14:41:24')
```

The Orders controller.

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  include CurrentBasket
  before_action :set_basket, only: [:new, :create]
  before_action :set_order, only: [:show, :edit, :destroy]

  def index
      @orders = Order.all 
    end

    def new
        #@statuses = Status.all.map{ |c| [c.name, c,id] }
        if @basket.product_items.empty?
            redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Your Basket is Empty'
            return
        end
        response = SagaPay.get_session_key
        response_hash = JSON.parse(response.body)
        session[:expiry] = response_hash["expiry"]
        session[:merchantSessionKey] = response_hash["merchantSessionKey"]

        @order = Order.new


    end

    def create
        response = SagaPay.transcation_request(@basket,session[:merchantSessionKey],params["card-identifier"],params[:order][:name],params[:order][:address],params[:order][:city],params[:order][:postcode])
        @order = Order.new(order_params)
        @order.add_product_items_from_basket(@basket)
#       @order.status_id = params[:status_id]
        if response.code == "201"
            if @order.save
                Basket.destroy(session[:basket_id])
                session[:basket_id] = nil
                session[:merchantSessionKey] = nil
                session[:expiry] = nil
                response_hash = JSON.parse(response.body)
                # OrderNotifier.received(@order).deliver
                redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Thank You for Your Order!'
            else
              render :new, notice: 'Please check your form'
            end
        else
            p response_hash = JSON.parse(response.body)
            flash[:alert] = "Please check your card details.#{response_hash['statusDetail']}"
            render :new, notice: "Please check your card details.#{response_hash['statusDetail']}"
        end
    end

    def show
         @orders = Order.where(id: params[:id])
    end

    def destroy
        @order.destroy
        redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Order deleted'
    end

    def edit
        @statuses = Status.all.map{ |c| [c.name, c,id] }
    end

    def update
    @order.status_id = params[:status_id]

    if @order.update(order_params)
        redirect_to order_path(@order)
    else 
        render 'edit'
    end

end



    private

    def set_order
        @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    end

    def order_params
        params.require(:order).permit(:name, :email, :address, :city, :county, :postcode, :ddate1, :ddate2, :ddate3)
    end

end
```

I have tried different input types and

Sorry if its a bit of a mess, I'm trying to convert a Asp.net site to ruby. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: It would be much easier to understand your code if you would reduce it to the relevant parts. Also it would help to see the server log.

Comment: I have removed the commented out code to make it shorter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using strong parameters to whitelist which require and permits only 
those elements listed on your `order_params permit method`

Currently you will be getting params as params[ddate3] while you are permitting the `dddate3` via orders i.e. params[order[ddate3]]

Now you need to set your dates as

```
var date_input=$('input[name="order[ddate3]"]')
```

and likewise.

Try this. Hope this Helps

Comment: Doing it this way seems to stop the date picker working and if I manually add the date and process the order then the same issue is happening.

Comment: okay then you can use rails syntax for the textfields for date inputs

Comment: In the form, I changed to this **name="order[ddate1]"**  and it is now working with the above.